# .Net CF: ComboBox.Text setting fails to match exact list item

Tags: .net, combobox

Compact Framework ComboBox issue. I have several items in the list, 2 of them are "M3" and "m3".  When using  ComboBox.Text="m3" in code, value only matches "M3".  It's matching the first letter without regard to exact match or case.

ComboBox doesn't have the auto-complete settings in CF as far as I know.
DropDownStyle is DropDownList.  I tried DropDown but it doesn't work consistently, plus I need it as a list.  I also tried SelectedValue.

Comment: Here's the workaround I'm using, it works with a small list of items I have; removing then inserting the M3 at the original position.

ComboBox.Items.Remove("M3")
ComboBox.Text = "m3"
ComboBox.Items.Insert(4, "M3")